# CUDA DLLs not found in R Shiny app (Tensorflow 2.8)

Tags: r, tensorflow, shiny

I have created an shiny app which uses TensorFlow which is running in my local machine but it is not working when I am publishing the app to shiny in local machine I am getting some error but the app is working fine
these are the errors

```
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
2022-05-09 10:07:18.177243: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:18.177956: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Loaded Tensorflow version 2.8.0
2022-05-09 10:07:31.370142: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.370919: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.371725: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.372487: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.373208: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.373897: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.374609: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.375352: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2022-05-09 10:07:31.375657: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2022-05-09 10:07:31.376921: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4313
```

And the folder structure of my app is

```
Classifer:
         rsconnect
         www:
             model
             label_list.R
         .RData
         .Rhistory
         app.R
```

And the code for app.R

```
model <- load_model_tf("./www/model")
load("./www/label_list.R")
target_size <- c(224,224,3)
options(scipen=999) #prevent scientific number formatting

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin="red",
  #(1) Header
  dashboardHeader(title=tags$h1("Classifier-App",style="font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold; color: white"),
                  titleWidth = 350,
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications", icon = icon("question-circle", "fa-1x"), badgeStatus = NULL,
                               headerText=""
                  )),
  
  
  #(2) Sidebar
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    width=350,
    fileInput("input_image","File" ,accept = c('.jpg','.jpeg')), 
    tags$br(),
    tags$p("Upload the image here.")
  ),
  
  
  #(3) Body
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    h4("Instruction:"),
    tags$br()"),
    tags$p(""),
    tags$p(""),
    tags$p(""),
    tags$br(),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(h4("Image:"),imageOutput("output_image"), width=6),
      column(h4("Result:"),tags$br(),textOutput("warntext",), tags$br(),
             tags$p("This Animal is probably a:"),tableOutput("text"),width=6)
    ),tags$br()
    
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  image <- reactive({image_load(input$input_image$datapath, target_size = target_size[1:2])})
  
  
  prediction <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$input_image)){return(NULL)}
    x <- image_to_array(image())
    x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
    x <- x/255
    pred <- model %>% predict(x)
    pred <- data.frame("Animal" = label_list, "Prediction" = t(pred))
    pred <- pred[order(pred$Prediction, decreasing=T),][1:5,]
    pred$Prediction <- sprintf("%.2f %%", 100*pred$Prediction)
    pred
  })
  
  output$text <- renderTable({
    prediction()
  })
  
  output$warntext <- renderText({
    req(input$input_image)
    
    if(as.numeric(substr(prediction()[1,2],1,4)) >= 30){return(NULL)}
    warntext <- "Warning: I am not sure about this Animal!"
    warntext
  })
  
  
  output$output_image <- renderImage({
    req(input$input_image)
    
    outfile <- input$input_image$datapath
    contentType <- input$input_image$type
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType=contentType,
         width = 400)
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And to upload the app I have followed this link:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/03/how-to-build-your-own-image-recognition-app-with-r-part-2/

Comment: Is the app working or not? It isn't clear from your language. It appears that the app can still launch albeit with errors

Comment: Please ignore all these warnings if the `GPU` is not installed on your local machine. They are just the information message as they are prefixed with `I`, if it is the error message they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings.Thank you.